# My data repeated when I search for any key word

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm warking to make a query that searching from two tables `patient` and `prescription` and I select columns for output from both tables. I use `inner join` and I want that when I write one word in `searchbox`, then it check it in one columns, if match then display it, and if not match then search in next column and so on.

For this purpose I make the following query, which is not complex at all, just some lengthy and I apply many `like` operators.

```
select distinct( pr.case_no) as CaseNo , 
       p.name as PatientName, 
       p.phone as PatientPhone,
       pr.visit_no as VisitNo,
       pr.assign_doctor as DoctorAssigned ,
       pr.date as  Date,
       pr.diet_chart as DietChart  
from  prescription pr, patient p 
where  p.p_id =pr.p_id 
       and 
       p.name like '%'+@input+'%' 
       or 
       pr.case_no  like '%'+@input+'%' 
       or 
       p.phone  like '%'+@input+'%' 
       or 
       pr.visit_no  like '%'+@input+'%' 
       or 
       pr.assign_doctor  like '%'+@input+'%' 
       or 
       pr.date  like '%'+@input+'%' 
       or 
       pr.diet_chart  like '%'+@input+'%'
```

When I write one word in `searchbox` then data repeated many times. I try my best to apply groups or distinct commands but no required output...

I want that one record display once, but it repeat the records.
The output of this query [image]
i want that data not repeat at all and makes the group on the basis of case_no........where query should be changed...please help

Comment: `from  prescription pr, patient p` **[`Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)**

Comment: what i should do for this purpose?

Comment: thank you ...i apply join other way that describe in the link page you sent....i apply this and it working well and give required output....

Comment: what "from  prescription pr, patient p 
where  p.p_id =pr.p_id" and "prescription_master pr inner join patient_info p on p.p_id =pr.p_id" have not same output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that AND has precedence over OR. therefore your where condition is equivalent to

```
WHERE
   ( p.p_id = pr.p_id 
     AND 
     p.name like '%'+@input+'%'
   )
   OR 
   pr.case_no  like '%'+@input+'%' 
   OR 
   p.phone  like '%'+@input+'%' 
   ...
```

add parentheses like this

```
WHERE
   p.p_id = pr.p_id 
   AND 
   ( p.name like '%'+@input+'%'
     OR 
     pr.case_no  like '%'+@input+'%' 
     OR 
     p.phone  like '%'+@input+'%' 
     ...
   )
```

However, as @Sami said, use the JOIN syntax:

```
SELECT pr.case_no,
    p.name as PatientName,
    p.phone as PatientPhone,
    pr.visit_no as VisitNo,
    pr.assign_doctor as DoctorAssigned ,
    pr.date as  Date,
    pr.diet_chart as DietChart  
FROM
    patient p
    LEFT JOIN prescription pr
        ON p.p_id = pr.p_id
WHERE
    p.name like '%'+@input+'%' OR
    pr.case_no  like '%'+@input+'%' OR
    p.phone  like '%'+@input+'%' OR
    pr.visit_no  like '%'+@input+'%' OR
    pr.assign_doctor  like '%'+@input+'%' OR
    pr.date  like '%'+@input+'%' OR
    pr.diet_chart  like '%'+@input+'%'
```

The LEFT JOIN has the advantage to return patients with no prescriptions; otherwise, with INNER JOIN, you will miss patients not yet having prescriptions. Also, you have a clear distinction between join conditions and additional filtering conditions.

Comment: i can't believe much little changes work well and i waste much time on this........ finally i appreciate your answer...